# Rack Request Log

Tags: ruby, logging, rack

### Why

Is there a reason Rack's request log by default outputs to stderr? If i'm not mistaken, the request log is Rack::CommonLogger which according to the RDoc:

> forwards every request to an app given, and logs a line in the Apache common log format to the logger, or rack.errors by default.

Doesn't it make more sense to have an access *and* error request log instead of pushing everything to rack.errors?

### How

How does one redirect the request log to a file? All examples I came across are specifically for sinatra. Can it be disabled completely? (redirect to /dev/null?)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question. But I hack a little this logger to switch logger like I want.

You can see the code here :

http://github.com/shingara/sinatra-request-logger/blob/master/lib/sinatra/request-logger.rb

Rack::CommonLogger use rack.errors where there are data. It's a StringIO by default. So you can't put a Logger inside. You need made a Proxy to put in your logger.